# MS project how to create alternative schedule to understand the impact of certain changes

Tags: ms-project, pm-software, schedule

We are using MS project professional.

**Question** : Assume I have a schedule A. There are 4 developers assigned to A as well. My management asks if they pull 2 resources out what will happen to the schedule.

1. Can I create an alternative schedule with 2 devs with existing tasks and constraints, estimates and compare with original schedule to understand the impact ? (Not a baseline)
2. Can you use a revisioning in MS project. For example I go ahead and
   create new schedule with 2 devs and call it revision 2. Once I
   understand the impact can I revert back to original revision ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of the original schedule by doing Save As. Then change the number of resources, let it calculate and save the new schedule (Rev 2). Use the built-in [Compare Projects](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-two-versions-of-a-project-4e19d66f-fd9e-48ef-aaf4-8bb045ba1473) feature to compare the two schedules (Report tab).

Comment: Thanks @Rachel Hettinger. This seems to work.